# Is there a standard for this "outdoor light systems connector"?

Tags: dc, connector, standard

I have a strand of LED Christmas lights I'd like to control with an ESP8266. It has a two-pin DC connector that attaches to a wall-wart adapter so ideally I would keep both and insert the ESP8266 controller in between. The connector looks exactly as shown in this picture from Wikipedia:

[image: outdoor light systems connector]

I'm trying to search for compatible solder-able parts (male and female), however, the article simply lists this as an ["outdoor light systems connector"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DC_connector#Outdoor_light_systems_connectors) without any other info which makes it difficult to search for. Is there a standard or model number for this kind of connector?

Comment: Should be able to [find a match](https://www.digikey.com/products/en/connectors-interconnects/circular-connectors/436?k=&pkeyword=&sv=0&pv88=121326&pv88=121386&sf=1&FV=-8%7C436&quantity=&ColumnSort=0&page=1&stock=1&pageSize=50), but you'll need to measure all sorts of dimensions to ensure an accurate fit.

Comment: Take a look at [What is the name used for this type of connectors?
](https://engineering.stackexchange.com/a/36884/110) There is list of outdoor lighting connector vendors.